# Apache Camel any shutdown hook for exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel and I'm trying to find a way how to "complete" running exchanges my way when shutdown (context stop) is initiated.

E.g. when I have simple servlet endpoint processing any HTTP request, I'd like to intercept shutdown and do the exchange completion on my own - like send some custom HTTP response with "Hey the application is being stopped".

I read and investigated code of ShutdownStrategy, RoutePolicy but still can't find a way where can i sneak into the real processing (get to threads in exchange/s).

In other words, I would need something similar to onException, something like onShutdown ... and do my own processing how the exchange should be completed instead of letting Apache Camel finish it and then kill it which may result in stack trace in the final HTTP response which is not acceptable.

What would also help may the way how to throw exception in all currently processed exchanges so I can make use of onException clause.

The closest I get was [this](http://qnalist.com/questions/2109122/custom-behavior-on-route-shutdown) response from 2011 which states that it is not possible. Anyway it is hard to believe that such important thing cannot be done.

The only solution (not nice really) that works only partially is that in custom RoutePolicy I stored (cached) every exchange when onExchangeBegin occurrs and before stopping the context, I called setException for every exchange. But this works only partially when you do transition between processors. It does not work when you have single long running processor.

Partially works:

```
public class MyRoutePolicy implements RoutePolicy {

    // can be made synchronized or utilize some lock
    public Collection<Exchange> exchanges = new ArrayList<>();

    public Collection<Exchange> getExchanges() {
        return exchanges;
    }

    @Override
    public void onExchangeBegin(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
        exchanges.add(exchange);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange) {
        exchanges.remove(exchange);
    }
    // other methods empty bodies
}


// in my stop method
for (Exchange exchange : policy.getExchanges()) {
   exchange.setException(new ShutdownException());
}
context.stop();


// in RouteBuilder
onException(ShutdownException.class)
   .process(new Processor() {
         @Override
         public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception 
            System.out.println("Here I'm doing my stuff");
         }
      })
   .handled(true)
   .stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe camel has anything directly like that, however, if you are using Spring you can have camel's shutdown depend on shutting down a spring bean with the 'depends-on' attribute.  Then the spring bean can implement disposable to allow for custom shutdown operations.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think there is no such Camel feature too. I wanted framework-free (except Camel) solution

Comment: Alright, it really seems there is no better way than the one I suggested in the question. I marking your answer as correct as you confirmed the thought.

Comment: Thanks!  you could also look at creating the solution with Camel and offering  it in a pull request to be maintained by the community.